# How to do Cartopy simple animations

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to create a simple animation using Cartopy. Basically just drawing a few lines in the map. So far I am trying the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()

lons = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)
lats = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)

def animate(i):

    plt.plot([lons[i-1], lons[i]], [lats[i-1], lats[i]], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    return plt

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=np.arange(1, 8), init_func=None, interval=2000, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to cartopy, I would guess. The problem is that you cannot return pyplot from the animation function. (It's like instead of buying a book, you'd buy the whole book store and then wonder why you can't read a book store.)

The easiest solution is to turn blitting off:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lons = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)
lats = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)

def animate(i):
    plt.plot([lons[i-1], lons[i]], [lats[i-1], lats[i]], color='blue')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=np.arange(1, 8), 
                               init_func=None, interval=200, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

If for some reason you need blitting (which would the case if the animation is too slow or consumes too much CPU), you need to return a list of the Line2D objects you want to draw.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lons = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)
lats = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)
lines = []

def animate(i):
    line, = plt.plot([lons[i-1], lons[i]], [lats[i-1], lats[i]])
    lines.append(line)
    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=np.arange(1, 8), 
                               interval=200, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.xlim(0,100) #<- remove when using cartopy
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Warining is

> The animation function must return a **sequence** of Artist objects

So just change the `blit` keyword from `True` to `false` and then save the animation into a gif file can solve this.

Otherwise, you can plot a sequence of Artist objects can then set the
`blit=True` as follows:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()

lons = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)
lats = 10 * np.arange(1, 10)

def animate(i):
    line = ax.plot([lons[i-1], lons[i]], [lats[i-1], lats[i]], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    return line

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=np.arange(1, 8), init_func=None, interval=200, blit=True)
anim.save('test.gif')
plt.show()
```

May these help you.